# Java println method error

Tags: java

I am trying to print times that it takes to do certain methods. I use

> double t0 = 0.01 * System.currentTimeMillis();
>   I have 3 times like that one.
>   And when I print it like this:

```
System.out.println("%7d    %10.7f       %10.7f", amount,
      (t1 - t0), (t2 - t1));
```

I get an error:

> no suitable method found for println(String,int,double,double)

Why is that? Where does that string parameter come from?

Comment: Use `printf` instead of `println` or you try `System.out.println(String.format("%7d    %10.7f       %10.7f", amount,
      (t1 - t0), (t2 - t1)));`

Comment: You are looking for `String.format()`

Comment: Because the signature for println takes a string on it's own.
You need to use String formatting outputs, see javadocs

Comment: The `printf` format needs a `%n` at the end.

Comment: thanks everyone could not figure it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You used `System.out.println()` which doesn't support adding arguments like you did in your program. Use `System.out.printf()` instead of that.

Answer (score 2):

use  this

```
String string = String.format("%7d    %10.7f       %10.7f", amount,
      (t1 - t0), (t2 - t1));
System.out.println(string);
```

reason: https://javapapers.com/core-java/system-out-println/

Answer (score 0):

println(xxx) is an overloaded method from class PrintStream (java.io.PrintStream)

go to command Prompt and enter

```
javap java.io.PrintStream
```

Then you get to see all the  methods present inside the PrintStream class , try to find the method "println(String,int,double,double)" , you wont find such method .

if you want to print multiple values , use println(java.lang.String) 
to print the value of int a=5;  int b=6;

`System.out.println(a+" "+b);`

the + operator is performing the string concatination and the whole expression in the () is consider as string .

you can also use the print() in java which behaves same like print() in c .
System.out.print(xxx); , it is also overload method.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this statement -:

```
System.out.println("%7d    %10.7f       %10.7f", amount,
      (t1 - t0), (t2 - t1));
```

Use this -: concatenate to get the output

```
System.out.println("%7d    %10.7f       %10.7f"+ amount+
      (t1 - t0)+ (t2 - t1));
```